# Laravel Task Scheduler on Windows Server

Tags: php, laravel, task, laravel-artisan, cron-task

I am trying to use the Laravel Task scheduler on a windows server but after various research, I can't figure out how to do this.

Obviously I can do this on linux but as I can understand triggering artisan from the windows task scheduler , is not enough.

Could you please help me out on this?

Comment: Check this forum post https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/running-schedulerun-on-windows/replies/56348

Answer (score 7, accepted):

here are the steps you should follow in order to perform the desired task

- 1 create a .bat file with the next content, I recommend to save
  this bat file inside a directory into your application folder.

> ```
>    cls 
>    cd C:\xampp\htdocs\ProjectName 
>    php artisan schedule:run dir
> ```

- 2 you must change C:\xampp\htdocs\ProjectName to the location of
  yout application and then save it.
- 3 press Windows + R, write Taskschd.msc and press enter
- 4 left click on Task Scheduler (Local) > click on 'create task'
- 5 In the 'general' tab write a Name for the task into the Name
  field
- 6 Check the radio button 'Run whether user is logged on or not'
- 7 In the tab 'Actions' click on 'New', in the field 'Action' select
  'Start a program'
- 8 Click on 'browse' and search and select the .bat file you just
  created and the press on 'OK'
- 9 In the tab 'Triggers' press on 'New'
- 10 In the Field 'Begin the task' select 'On a schedule'
- 11 In settings check radio button 'Daily' > in Start set the hour
  to 1:00:00 a.m. > in Recur every  set 1 days
- 12 Into advanced settings check 'Repeat task every' and set [ 5
  minutes +]  for a duration of [Indefinitely +]
- 13 In advanced settings the checkbox 'Enabled' must be checked
- 14 press OK
- 15 in the tab 'Settings' you must have the next configurations
          [/] Allow task to be run on demand
          [/] Run task as soon as possible after a scheduled start is missed
          [/] If the task fails, restart every 1 minute
          [/] Stop the task if it turns longer than 3 days
          [/] if the running task doesn´t end when requested force it to stop
          if the task is already running, then the following rule applies
                  [Queue a new instance +]
- 16 press the OK button, write the user password , and then you
  could start the task if you need

I hope this to be useful for you.