# Laravel Task Scheduler Server not working on Windows Server Xampp

Tags: windows, xampp, laravel-8, laravel-scheduler

Laravel Task Scheduler not works properly in windows XAMPP server. I make Database Auto backup script source. backup database is works fine but, Laravel scheduler not works properly in windows server

> `app/Console/Commands/DatabaseBackUp.php` file created using `php artisan make:command DatabaseBackUp` command

```
<?php

namespace App\Console\Commands;

use Illuminate\Console\Command;
use Carbon\Carbon;

class DatabaseBackUp extends Command
{
    /**
     * The name and signature of the console command.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $signature = 'database:backup';

    /**
     * The console command description.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $description = 'Command description';

    /**
     * Create a new command instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    /**
     * Execute the console command.
     *
     * @return int
     */
    public function handle()
    {
        $filename = "backup-" . Carbon::now()->format('Y-m-d') . ".sql";

        $command = "". env('DUMP_COMMAND_PATH') ." --user=" . env('DB_USERNAME') ." --password=" . env('DB_PASSWORD') . " --host=" . env('DB_HOST') . " " . env('DB_DATABASE') . " > " . storage_path() . "/app/backup/" . $filename;
  
        $returnVar = NULL;
        $output  = NULL;
  
        exec($command, $output, $returnVar);
        dd("Database backup Successfully Done - $filename Time:- ".Carbon::now());
    }
}
?>
```

> `app/Console/Kernel.php` file

```
<?php

namespace App\Console;

use Illuminate\Console\Scheduling\Schedule;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel as ConsoleKernel;

class Kernel extends ConsoleKernel
{
    /**
     * The Artisan commands provided by your application.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $commands = [
        'App\Console\Commands\DatabaseBackUp'
    ];

    /**
     * Define the application's command schedule.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Console\Scheduling\Schedule  $schedule
     * @return void
     */
    protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
    {
        // $schedule->command('inspire')->hourly();
        $schedule->command('database:backup')
                    ->daily()
                    ->appendOutputTo(storage_path('logs/db-backups.log'));
    }

    /**
     * Register the commands for the application.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    protected function commands()
    {
        $this->load(__DIR__.'/Commands');

        require base_path('routes/console.php');
    }
}
```

Now when I hit `php artisan database:backup` command manually then it is create Database backup...

but as per [Official Doc. of Laravel 8](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/scheduling#running-the-scheduler) when I hit `cd C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel-project && php artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1` command it shows error like `The system cannot find the path specified.`

but when I hit the `php artisan schedule:run` command then it create database backup only once. not repeat task as we mentioned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in Laravel Docs there are mentioned scheduler start command `cd /path-to-your-project && php artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1` it is works for Linux crontab Feature, for Windows we need to use Task Scheduler

**for Linux**

```
crontab -e

* * * * * php /path/to/artisan schedule:run 1>> /dev/null 2>&1
```

OR

```
* * * * * cd /path-to-your-project && php artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1
```

For **Windows (Trick 1)**

1. create .bat file in your applications directory

> db-Backup.bat file

write following line in db-Backup.bat file & save it

```
cd C:\xampp\htdocs\microtechcoupon && C:\xampp\php\php artisan schedule:run
```

2.press Windows + R, write Taskschd.msc and press enter & Task Scheduler will opens,
3. [image: Click on Create Task]

4. fill the inputs fields as per need. for more detail [see here how to fill fields in Task scheduler](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38779137)

- 
- 

---

For **Windows (Trick 2)**

> **If you wants to prevent command line won’t popup every single minute when scheduler runs your task. then you can use 2nd trick**

1. press Windows + R, write Taskschd.msc and press enter & open Task Scheduler
2. fill the fields. **but In the tab 'Actions' click on 'New', in the field 'Action' select
   'Start a program'**
3. then in settings section fill `C:\xampp\php\php.exe` in Program/Script input field & `C:\xampp\htdocs\microtechcoupon\artisan schedule:run` in Add arguments (optional) field & then save it

credit of 2nd Trick in windows :- https://quantizd.com/how-to-use-laravel-task-scheduler-on-windows-10/