# Crontab -e not recognized

Tags: laravel, cron, command

I have been searching from multiple sources about how to set the cronjob in server. I have been following the tutorial from
https://www.positronx.io/laravel-cron-job-task-scheduling-tutorial-with-example/

also from
https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/scheduling

However, when trying to apply the crontab -e and customizing the cronjob it  is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

[Result of the command](https://i.stack.imgur.com/soKn8.png)

I am using windows and WAMPP and laravel

Comment: Because `crontab` is a Linux/Unix command. Use the Windows scheduler (I think that's what it's called) or use a more specific search like "crontab windows" on the web

Comment: @brombeer I found that if windows we have to use the windows task scheduler, if, by chance I still want to use the cron tab using the power shell on widnows is it possible?

Comment: @Tina as brombeer said, there is no crontab in a windows environment. Task Scheduler is the windows way of handeling this. However I wonder why you would run Laravel on WAMPP. isn't that really slow?

Comment: see this answer for set windows task scheduler https://stackoverflow.com/a/69954322/14344959